# Fatal error: exactly/the/good/way/class not found

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

**I got the Fatal Error:**
Fatal error: Class 'app\Autoloader' not found in C:\wamp64\www\WE\index.php
**In other words:**
Fatal error: exactly/the/good/way/class not found

begin of my script index.php

```
<?php
use \app\Autoloader;
Autoloader::register();
```

**Begin of my autoloader script:**

```
namespace app;
class Autoloader{...}
```

**Arborescence**:

- Racine local server

  - app

    - [...]
    - Autoloader.php
- index.php

Why this fatal error ?? The way mentionned in the error php is right...
Thaks for help !

Comment: Please give us more informations. Can you give your autoloader's code ? Where is the index.php file ?

Comment: i just edited the post to show you where is the index.php, the autoloader code no matter here, my autoloader is empty, he just cant find it...

Comment: We absolutely need your autoloader, including the `::register` static function which causes the error.

Comment: My autoloader is EMPTY there is no code inside, he just cant find it. That is the problem

Comment: There is one of your file that is using the `exactly\the\good\way\class` class !

Comment: Could you be more accurate plz ? because only this class use this way..

Answer (score 0):

The use statement will need to have the class available first. Since you haven't added the autoloader, you'll have to `require_once` the PHP file containing the autoloader, then `use` the class to import it into your namespace.

After the autoloader is present, it will have the responsibility of finding and loading the classes as they're `use`'d.